# On edit function, Timestamp and dependent access on column to update in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Am trying to make it possible, After updated previous step use can update next step and i will get timestamp for all updates.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = "Not Open";
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  var checkbox = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 45).getValue();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetName && editedColumn == 51 && editedRow > 2 && checkbox == false) {
    Browser.msgBox("You Can't Complete This Task Befor Previous task Done");
        e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
  
  }

addTimestamp(e);

}
  function addTimestamp(e)
{

  //variables
  var startRow = 8;
  var targetColumn45 = 45;
  var targetColumn51 = 51;
  var WS = "Not Open";
  
  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  
 if(col === targetColumn45 && row >= startRow  && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === WS) {

    var currentDate = new Date();

  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 43).setValue(currentDate); 
  e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
  
  }
  
  if(col === targetColumn51 && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === WS) {

    var currentDate = new Date();

  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 49).setValue(currentDate); 
  

  }
 
   
}
```

I have to create one process having 10 steps to complete one work.
step 1,2,3 will start when new form submitted with new entry.
step 4,5,6 will start after completion of step 3.
continue......

end of process
At the end I will get total days to complete one task and delay time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edit and timestamp function together based on one cell value